# Node.js a lot better in ab without clustering, what I'm missing?

Tags: node.js, concurrency, apachebench

**Update 1**: @BagosGiAr tests with a quite similar configuration shows the cluster always should perform better. That is, there is some problem with my configuration, and I'm asking you to help me find out what could be.

**Update 2**: I'd like to go in deep of this problem. I've tested on a LiveCD* (Xubuntu 13.04), same node version. First thing is that, with Linux, performances are way better than Windows: `-n 100000 -c 1000` gives me 6409.85 reqs/sec without cluster, 7215.74 reqs/sec with clustering. Windows build has definitely a lot of problems. Still I want to investigate why this is happening only to me, given that some people with a similar configuration perform better (and clustering performs well too).

*It should be noted that LiveCD uses a RAM filesystem, while in Windows I was using a fast SSD.

How this is possible? Shouldn't result be better with `cluster` module? Specs: Windows 7 x64, Dual Core P8700 2.53Ghz, 4GB RAM, Node.js 0.10.5, ab 2.3. Test command line is `ab -n 10000 -c 1000 http://127.0.0.1:8080/`.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.end('Hello World');
}).listen(8080);
```

Benchmark result ~ **2840.75 reqs/second**:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1430300 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        12 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   3.520 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      870000 bytes
HTML transferred:       120000 bytes
Requests per second:    2840.75 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       352.020 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.352 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          241.35 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   7.1      0     505
Processing:    61  296 215.9    245    1262
Waiting:       31  217 216.7    174    1224
Total:         61  297 216.1    245    1262

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    245
  66%    253
  75%    257
  80%    265
  90%    281
  95%    772
  98%   1245
  99%   1252
 100%   1262 (longest request)
```

With cluster module:

```
var cluster = require('cluster'),
    http = require('http'),
    numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Fork workers
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('worker ' + worder.process.pid + ' died');
    });
} else {
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.end('Hello World');
    }).listen(8080);
}
```

... and with the same benchmark, result is worst: **849.64 reqs/sec**:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1430300 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        12 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   11.770 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      870000 bytes
HTML transferred:       120000 bytes
Requests per second:    849.64 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1176.967 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.177 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          72.19 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1  21.3      0     509
Processing:    42 1085 362.4   1243    2274
Waiting:       27  685 409.8    673    1734
Total:         42 1086 362.7   1243    2275

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   1243
  66%   1275
  75%   1286
  80%   1290
  90%   1334
  95%   1759
  98%   1772
  99%   1787
 100%   2275 (longest request)
```

Comment: Can you append your benchmark test code plz?

Comment: I could be wrong here, and this is why I am not posting a separate answer, but I don't think clustering adds any benefit for small test code as yours, rather it simply acts as a bottleneck.

Comment: @Munim while you could be right, there are a lot of example showing that cluster helps, even with this simple code. Would you add CPU intensive code, like rendering a template, to start seeing some benefit?

Comment: @Munim but the interesting fact is still. Either you're right cluster shouldn't reduce the performance that much.

Comment: In your machine, windows and other programs will constantly burden your two core CPU. One core is constantly in use for system processes. So making it use two cores will reduce the performance for both cluster processes due to constant context switching. Multi-threaded applications don't perform that well if there are many concurrent processes hogging CPU.

Comment: @user568109 I did some tests in Xubuntu and there are some improvements in cluster vs non-cluster. Still using the same machine, with two cores. I've updated the question if you are interested.

Comment: I don't have windows, so I can't test, but do note that Cluster initially uses a different scheduling policy in Windows. You can force it to use RoundRobin (which is what is used in *nix) by setting the environment variable NODE_CLUSTER_SCHED_POLICY to "rr". I don't really have an idea how much this will affect performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving port number 8080 in your url address.

By default 80 is used when no port given.(8080 is default port used for Apache Tomcat). Maybe another server is listening on port 80 on your machine.

#### Update

Machine Specs : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5650 @ 2.67GHz, 64GB RAM,CentOS Linux release 6.0 (Final), node -v 0.8.8, ab -V 2.3

I think the problem in your case is that either Windows is not efficiently using the resources or CPU or RAM is being saturated when you run the benchmark.

Without cluster (used the same script)

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 10.232.5.169 (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 9000 requests
Completed 10000 requests
Finished 10000 requests


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        10.232.5.169
Server Port:            8000

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        11 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   3.196 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      860000 bytes
HTML transferred:       110000 bytes
Requests per second:    3129.14 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       319.577 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.320 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          262.80 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    3  43.0      0    2999
Processing:     1   81  39.9     81     201
Waiting:        1   81  39.9     81     201
Total:         12   84  57.8     82    3000

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     82
  66%    103
  75%    114
  80%    120
  90%    140
  95%    143
  98%    170
  99%    183
 100%   3000 (longest request)
```

With cluster (used your cluster script)

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 10.232.5.169 (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 9000 requests
Completed 10000 requests
Finished 10000 requests


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        10.232.5.169
Server Port:            8000

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        11 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   1.056 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      924672 bytes
HTML transferred:       118272 bytes
Requests per second:    9467.95 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       105.620 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.106 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          854.96 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       22   47  13.6     46      78
Processing:    23   52  13.8     52     102
Waiting:        5   22  17.6     17      83
Total:         77   99   5.8    100     142

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    100
  66%    101
  75%    102
  80%    102
  90%    104
  95%    105
  98%    110
  99%    117
 100%    142 (longest request)
```

Comment: Oh sorry, the missing port number was a mistake while typing. Fixed.

Comment: Can you tally the results again. I ran the same on my machine and it came 3127.07 reqs/sec without cluster and 9764.46 reqs/sec with cluster. You didn't copy transfer rate by mistake right (262.63 KB/sec and 884.52 KB/sec respectively)

Comment: Can you post your machine specs and the node scripts? I've updated the question. By the way using node alone without clustering is clearly faster even only looking at the benchmark window.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a result for not using the concurrent option of ApacheBench. as a default `ab` makes one request at the time, so the each request (in the cluster test) is served by one node and the rest of them stay idle. If you use the `-c` option you will benchmark the cluster mode of nodejs.
eg 
`ab -n 10000 -c 4 -t 25 http://127.0.0.1:8083/` 
My result are: 
Without cluster `ab -n 10000 -t 25 http://127.0.0.1:8083/`:

```
Server Software:
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8083

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        11 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   16.503 seconds
Complete requests:      50000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      4300000 bytes
HTML transferred:       550000 bytes
Requests per second:    3029.66 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       0.330 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.330 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          254.44 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.3      0       1
Processing:     0    0   0.4      0      13
Waiting:        0    0   0.4      0      11
Total:          0    0   0.5      0      13

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      0
  66%      0
  75%      1
  80%      1
  90%      1
  95%      1
  98%      1
  99%      1
 100%     13 (longest request)
```

With cluster `ab -n 10000 -c 4 -t 25 http://127.0.0.1:8083/`:

```
Server Software:
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8083

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        11 bytes

Concurrency Level:      4
Time taken for tests:   8.935 seconds
Complete requests:      50000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      4300000 bytes
HTML transferred:       550000 bytes
Requests per second:    5595.99 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       0.715 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.179 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          469.98 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.3      0       1
Processing:     0    1   0.6      1      17
Waiting:        0    0   0.6      0      17
Total:          0    1   0.6      1      18

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      1
  66%      1
  75%      1
  80%      1
  90%      1
  95%      1
  98%      1
  99%      1
 100%     18 (longest request)
```

Cheers!

**EDIT**
I forgot my specifications; Windows 8x64, intel core i5-2430M @ 2.4GHz, 6GB RAM

Comment: During the last edit of my question I've removed the `ab` command line used. By the way I'm using a concurrency level of 1000 (`-c 1000`). I've edited the question again, showing the command used.

Comment: Which node version are you using?

Comment: same, v0.10.5. I've just raise the -c to 1000 as you and the result is the same, cluster works better.

Comment: So you confirmed that the question remains unanswered. There is some problem with my configuration, but I think it will be hard to find.

Comment: it could be a firewall, which often seems trivial in windows. But yes I think it's a configuration of your machine, could be the nodeJS itself or either your Windows OS.

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I've tried, disable the firewall and antivirus. No changes.

Comment: Could you lower the request rate for both cases just to be sure that your Windows is not running out of resources. Both `-n` & `-c` options, in fact assign to `-c` the number of your CPU Cores.

Comment: With `-n 1000 -c 2` I got: 3067 wo cluster, 2500 w cluster. Again, worst with cluster.